# ng-grid with "select all" checkbox without showing a checkbox for each row

Tags: jquery, angularjs, checkbox, ng-grid

I would like to know if there is a way to have a grid with the first column empty except for the header that must contain the "`Select All`" checkbox.

Using this code I have all the column full of checkboxes but setting "`showSelectionCheckbox:false`" also check "`Select All`" checkbox is hidden.

There is any way to do this ?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.mySelections = [];
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
      data: 'myData',
      checkboxHeaderTemplate: '<input class="ngSelectionHeader" type="checkbox" ng-model="allSelected" ng-change="toggleSelectAll(allSelected)"/>',
      showSelectionCheckbox: true,
      selectWithCheckboxOnly: false,
      selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
      multiSelect: true
    };
    });
   </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
        <div class="selectedItems">{{mySelections}}</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `checkboxCellTemplate` and set the style for the `input` to `display:none`

```
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.mySelections = [];
        $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                         {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                         {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                         {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                         {name: "Enos", age: 34}];


        var ct_nocheck="<div class=\"ngSelectionCell\"><input style=\"display:none\" tabindex=\"-1\" class=\"ngSelectionCheckbox\" type=\"checkbox\" ng-checked=\"row.selected\" /></div>";                     

        $scope.gridOptions = { 
          data: 'myData',
          checkboxHeaderTemplate: '<input class="ngSelectionHeader" type="checkbox" ng-model="allSelected" ng-change="toggleSelectAll(allSelected)"/>',
          showSelectionCheckbox: true,
          selectWithCheckboxOnly: false,
          checkboxCellTemplate:ct_nocheck,
          selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
          multiSelect: true
        };

    });
```

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3VYZdi?p=preview)

Another way would be to add:

```
.ngSelectionCheckbox{
  display:none;
}
```

to your CSS.

Here is another [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/of95Le?p=preview)

Comment: Since you are here for the first time I recommend to spent 2 Minutes on taking the Tour in the help pulldown in the black bar at the top of this page. It is common to mark an answer as "Accepted" when it was helpfull for you. This way other users with the same issue can find the answer too. Knowing the rules of SO will get you more help and less downvotes in further questions. Anyhow, glad I could help you!